# plt.show won't display figure, backend is fine, code does what it should, looked everywhere

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu-18.04

I'm playing around with plotting in python (3.6.8) using matplotlib (2.2.4) and I have the following code:

```py
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.show
```

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, calling this from a bash shell with:

```
$ python3 code.py
```

I expect it to show me a figure of y vs. x but instead, no figure shows up and I just get the bash prompt back. I checked and my instance of python is using 'TkAgg' so it's not a backend issue. I've also put print statements in the body of the code that computes x and y (it's just some algebra and a few calls to numpy) to verify that everything is working as it should be and their output looks normal so I don't think the issue is somewhere else. At this point I've read through just about every thread I can find on the issue and the problem persists.

Help please

Thank you ( :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `plt.show()`. You're missing the parentheses.